# executing threads with no synchronization

Tags: threads

suppose Threads 1 and 2 are executing concurrently with shared integer variables A, B, and C. Thread 1 executes:A=4, B=5, C=B-A; Thread 2 executes: A=3, B=6, C=A+B;

I'm trying to find what can the possible values of C be after execution of this fragment when synchronization is not implemented.

I know if there is no synchronization then the reads see writes that occur later in the execution order and it will be counter intuitive ( execution will be happens-before consistency)

I am confused what can be the possible values of C. Can the possible values for C be 1,2,3,8,9,10 after substituting the all possible values for A & B from both thread 1 and thread 2 for C=B-A & C=A+B

Comment: What do you think? Can you come up with executions supporting your set of possible values? Can you show that no other possible values are possible?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus. I came up with thread 1 executed A=4, B=5, C becomes B-A = 1, thread 2 executed A=3, B=6, C=A+B= 9, likewise in execution A=4, B=6 ,C=B-A=2;A=3, B=5, C=B-A =2;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Let $C = B \pm A$ be the final instruction being executed. Clearly $A \in \{3,4\}$ and $B \in \{5,6\}$, and this shows that $C \in \{1,2,3,8,9,10\}$. For the other direction, show that by carefully scheduling both threads, you can choose which of $C = B \pm A$ is executed last, and choose the value that $A$ and $B$ get prior to that instruction being executed.